# Could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scala.reflect.ClassManifest[T]

Tags: scala, types

It seems I don't understand something important, maybe about erasure (damn it).

I have a method, which I wanted to create array of size `n` filled with values from `gen`:

```
def testArray[T](n: Int, gen: =>T) {
  val arr = Array.fill(n)(gen)
  ...
}
```

And use it, for example as:

```
testArray(10, util.Random.nextInt(10))
```

But I get error:

```
scala: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scala.reflect.ClassManifest[T]
val arr = Array.fill(n)(gen)
                       ^
```

Please, explain what I did wrong, why this error, and what kind of code it makes impossible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is because in `testArray` the concrete type of `T` is not known at compile time. Your signature has to look like `def testArray[T : ClassManifest](n: Int, gen: =>T)`, this will add an implicit parameter of type `ClassManifest[T]` to your method, that is automatically passed to the call of `testArray` and then further passed to the `Array.fill` call. This is called a `context bound`.

Comment: Indeed, that helps. ClassManifest as I slightly remember is a tool to deal with type erasure? May, you please explain how construct `[T : ClassManifest]` actually resolves the problem? Passes around implictly the instance of `ClassManifest[T]` from where `T` is known?

Comment: By the way I have one more similar problem :) Inside the `testArray` after `Array.fill` I'm trying to instantiate class which uses implicit Ordering, declared as `MyClass[T](seq: Array[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T])`. So, on `new MyClass(arr)` I see `No implicit Ordering defined for T`. Any chance I can use manifest to solve this? Maybe instantiate ordering using ClassManifest?

Comment: To get an instance of `Ordering[A]` simply add is as context bound. `def testArray[T : ClassManifest : Ordering](n: Int, gen: =>T)`. As I already wrote in the post, the compiler will pass through the implicit instances when you add context bounds to your type parameters.

Comment: The notation `[T : Bound]` in `def m[T : Bound](arg: Type) = ...` is syntactic sugar for `def m[T](arg: Type)(implicit tBound: Bound[T]) = ...`.

Answer (score 5):

The `Array.fill` method has the following signature:

```
def fill[T](n: Int)(elem: => T)(implicit arg0: ClassManifest[T]): Array[T]
```

In order to get an instance of `ClassManifest[T]` you need to know the concrete type. A `ClassManifest` can be obtained like this:

```
implicitly[ClassManifest[String]]
```

A `ClassManifest` is implicitly available for every concrete type.

For any `implicit` error, you can add the implicits you require to the method with the type parameter:

```
def wrap[T](n:Int)(elem: => T)(implicit c:ClassManifest[T], o:Ordering[T])
```

If you did not yourself introduce `ClassManifest` or `Ordering`, the writers of the library have (most likely) provided sensible defaults for you.

If you would call the `wrap` method:

```
wrap(2)(3)
```

It's expanded like this:

```
wrap[Int](2)(3)(implicitly[ClassManifest[Int]], implicitly[Ordering[Int]])
```

If you introduced a custom class `Person` here, you would get an error for not finding an implicit instance of `Ordering[Person]`. The writers of the library could not have known how to order `Person`. You could solve that like this:

```
class Person

implicit val o = new Ordering[Person] { // implement required methods }

wrap(2)(new Person)
```

The Scala compiler looks in different scopes for implicits, an `Ordering` would usually not be specified like this. I suggest you look up implicit resolution on the internet to learn more about it.